# Xcode gives different memory usage than my code

Tags: swift, xcode, memory

I want to track memory usage of my app. My code doesn't give me same value as Xcode does (in the debug navigator view)

```
func report_memory() {
        var info = mach_task_basic_info()
        var count = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<mach_task_basic_info>.size)/4

        let kerr: kern_return_t = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &info) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: 1) {
                task_info(mach_task_self_,
                          task_flavor_t(MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO),
                          $0,
                          &count)
            }
        }

        if kerr == KERN_SUCCESS {
            let unit = UInt64(1024 * 1024)
            let memUsage = info.resident_size / unit
            print("Memory in use (in MB): \(memUsage)")
        } else {
            print("Error with task_info(): " +
                (String(cString: mach_error_string(kerr), encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) ?? "unknown error"))
        }
    }
```

My code (running on simulator): **139MB**

Xcode : **84MB**

Do you have an idea why? Thanks!